# Why does Tonks say ‘wotcher’?

Tags: harry-potter

Tonks says ‘wotcher’ all the time.

Especially when she meets someone, she says ‘Wotcher’ instead of ‘Hello’.

What does it mean?

Comment: What'ya up ta? What'ya'doin'

Comment: 'What cheer', she's northern

Comment: Discussed here on another stack; [Is the word “wotcher” British slang? What does it mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4812/is-the-word-wotcher-british-slang-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: "*In C.20 often rendered _watcher_ or _wotcher_, and thought of as mainly Cockney, it is a greeting going back early C.18, if not earlier. James Isham uses it in _Observations and Notes_, 1743 (Hudson's Bay Record Soc., XII, 54: Leechman). _EDD_ notes it as Yorkshire dial., ca. 1860. 'The universal greeting of labourers and countrymen' (David Garnett, _New Statesman & Nation_, 20 Feb. 1937).*
 - ***A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English, 8th ed. by Eric Partridge & Paul Beale***

Comment: (starts humming "gin gan gooley-gooley-gooley-gooley wotcher, gin-gan-goo, gin-gan-goo"...)

Answer (score 6):

**Wotcher** is a [greeting](https://www.lexico.com/definition/wotcher), like watcha or what cheer.

Answer (score 3):

Wotcher definition

> A British slang term formed by the contraction of "What are you up to?" "Wot'cher up ta?" devolved into this now-common greeting. See also wotcha. "Wotcher, Harry! Good to see ya, mate!"
>
> https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wotcher

Comment: Urban dictionary is a very poor source of etymological insight.

Comment: @Valorum I disagree ;-P